# How can I stop mouth breathing while I sleep?

Tags: sleep-apnea

I've been diagnosed with sleep apnea and am currently treating it with an [apap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_airway_pressure#Mechanism_of_action). When I was fitted for the apap (and associated masks), the provider told me that if I start drooling I should call them and ask for a chin strap. Drooling is a sign that I am breathing through my mouth, and since the apap mask only covers my nose I shouldn't be doing that.

After about a year with the apap, I finally gave in to my dentist's urging that I wear a mouthguard to sleep because I'm grinding my teeth (and broke a crown). Now with the mouthguard, I started drooling in my sleep.

I dutifully called the medical equipment provider and asked for a chin strap like I was instructed. However, the chin strap interferes with the fitting of my mask so I keep waking up at night with air blowing in my face. I don't like it and I haven't been using it.

Is there another solution for mouth breathing besides a chin strap?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can get a full face mask and then it wont matter if you are breathing through your mouth or not. I would contact your medical equipment provider again and see what they have in options for full face masks. Personally I use Quattro full face mask and have no issues with it.

You can look [here](http://www.cpap.com/cpap-masks/full-face-cpap-mask.php) for an idea of what masks are out there to chose from.

You can also check [here](http://www.cpaptalk.com/CPAP-Sleep-Apnea-Forum.html) for more information and a group that will be able to answer questions about a wide variety of masks and they might have a solution to help you with your current problem without having to switch mask styles.